# Unity 5: How to pass multiple parameters on button click function from inspector?

Tags: c#, uibutton, parameter-passing, unity-game-engine

I want to send multiple parameter on button click from inspector?

Unity isn't allowing that to do, how can I achieve that? is there any other way?
There are dozens of buttons and I am using same method for all buttons but sending different parameters, now I need to send multiple types of parameters. Can't figure out how?

Comment: You can't do this from the inspector. What datatypes do you need to pass with the button?

Comment: integer and strings

Comment: Let's just say I want to pass hard coded values. Because I know for what specific reason they are going to be used so I pass specific values.

Comment: Right now I am using multiple methods for multiple variables to be set. I call them on same button and pass different values of different data types

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Calling Unity function from the Editor has limitation. It can only take one parameter and the function must be a non `static` function.

This is why it is important to know how to subscribe to events from code. Below is an example of a function that gets called when a `Button` is clicked. It passes in a string and an integer to that function. Simple, drag the `Button` to the **some Button** slot in the Editor and this should work.

```
public Button someButton;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Events
    someButton.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack("Hello Affan", 88));
}

private void buttonCallBack(string myStringValue, int myIntValue)
{
    Debug.Log("Button Clicked. Received string: " + myStringValue + " with int: " + myIntValue);
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register Button Events
    someButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Comment: The whole point of calling it from the editor is that you don't know what the callback is. Sure, if you know what it is your solution is fine. But what if you're developing an asset and the callback is defined by the user, for example?