# How to pass the value by clicking UI button in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, logic

**How to pass the value by clicking UI button in unity**

i have 4 buttons in my scene so what i want to do means

button A have 5
button B have 25
button C have 2
button D have 7

EXAMPLE:
If i click the button A and Button B value 30

and how to detect the button is clicked first time and second time ??

Please Help me out thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518903/unity-5-how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-on-button-click-function-from-inspector

Answer (score 1):

To pass a value in a UI button you can use a public function with one parameter.

[image]

Here's an example code using switch to detect which button was clicked, and a dictionary to count clicks for each button.

```
    int sum;
Dictionary<string, int> clickCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
void Start()
{
    clickCounts.Add("A", 0);
    clickCounts.Add("B", 0);
    clickCounts.Add("C", 0);
    clickCounts.Add("D", 0);
}

public void ButtonClick(string buttonLetter)
{
    switch (buttonLetter)
    {
        case "A":
            sum += 5;
            clickCounts["A"]++;
            break;
        case "B":
            sum += 25;
            clickCounts["B"]++;
            break;
        case "C":
            sum += 2;
            clickCounts["C"]++;
            break;
        case "D":
            sum += 7;
            clickCounts["D"]++;
            break;
    }
}
```