# Public Function cant be found in OnClick Event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have an Inventory and the Items have MataData, that I am scanning for. Although when I try to hook up the public void to the OnClick selection on the Button, it does not show up, why?
Code Snipped:

```
public void ScanForFlashlightMetaData(string type, string Flashlight)
    {
        foreach (Slot slot in inventory)
        if (slot.type == type && slot.metaData == Flashlight)
        {
            Debug.Log("Test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "hook up the public void to the OnClick selection" and "it does not show up"?

Comment: In unity you have a button, where you can drag in a script(e.g. TestScript). If you click on "No function", you can select a function (e.g. public void TestFunction()). I have the problem that the function does not show up there, Even weirder is that if I remove the "string Flashlight" and the "&& slot.metaData == Flashlight", it works, which I cant explain?

Comment: @GabrielLuci ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback functions assigned to `ButtonClickEvent` can only take zero or one parameters (which is why it shows up when you remove them).

Try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518903/unity-5-how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-on-button-click-function-from-inspector) for workarounds, or consider creating a custom `Button` class that uses the generic `UnityEvent<T0, T1, ...>` which supports up to four arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware that I could only use 1 parameter for this. Helped a lot =)