# Button OnClick() not detecting public method

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have looked at other answers, but it hasnt helped because I did add the object and not the script in the OnClick() box, but it still won't let me access the variable. What's going on?

[The object in the box, not the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTf0K.png)

[The Method I want to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RHyf.png)

```
public void IncreaseStat(string stat, float val)
{
    switch (stat)
    {
        case "Hunger":
            gm.juice.hunger += val;
            break;
        case "Energy":
            gm.juice.energy += val;
            break;
        case "Happiness":
            gm.juice.happiness += val;
            break;
        case "Health":
            gm.juice.health += val;
            break;
        default:
            Debug.LogError("INVALID STAT: " + stat);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity 5: How to pass multiple parameters on button click function from inspector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518903/unity-5-how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-on-button-click-function-from-inspector)

Comment: You have multiple parameters in your method, Unity's inspector for ```Button``` only allows one. You'll probably have to use the ```addListener``` method (described in the linked question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like Unity not allow you to put function with more than one parameter into the OnClick() event

```html
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonEventDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void FunctionWithNoParams()
    {
        // This is working fine
    }

    public void FunctionWithStringParam(string text)
    {
        // This is working fine
    }

    public void FunctionWithIntParam(int number)
    {
        // This is working fine
    }

    public void FunctionWithButtonParam(Button button)
    {
        // This is working fine
    }

    public void FunctionWithTwoParams(int first, int second)
    {
        // Cannot put this function into OnClick() event
    }
}
```

[OnClick() demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpipb.png)